# Android : suppress multiple invocations of coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

Is there any good idea to suppress multiple invocations of coroutines in Android + kotlin?

I've written the following code. It works for my purposes, but I'm wondering if there's a smarter way to write it.

```kotlin
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    
    private val mutex = Mutex()
    private var job : Job? = null

    fun processCoroutine() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            mutex.withLock {
                if (job == null) {
                    job = viewModelScope.launch {

                        // heavy process                 

                        mutex.withLock {
                            job = null
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have actually tried the suggedted codes.

https://github.com/Nunocky/CoroutineStudy01

Some of them needed some modifications, but all of them worked stable :-D

Answer (score 0):

If you access the `job` property exclusively from the main thread, it can be simpler.

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    
    private var job : Job? = null // main thread only

    @MainThread
    fun processCoroutine() {
        if (job != null) {
            return
        }
        job = viewModelScope.launch {
            // heavy process
            // ...
            job = null
        }
    }

    // If needed...
    @MainThread
    fun cancelCoroutine() {
        job?.cancel()
        job = null
    }

}
```

If you want your functions to be callable from any thread:

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel() {
    
    private var job : Job? = null // main thread only

    fun processCoroutine() = viewModelScope.launch {
        if (job != null) {
            return@launch
        }
        job = viewModelScope.launch {
            // heavy process
            // ...
            job = null
        }
    }

    // If needed...
    fun cancelCoroutine() = viewModelScope.launch {
        job?.cancel()
        job = null
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether `Job` is `active` and only it if is inactive then invoke again

```
private var job: Job = Job()
fun processCoroutine2() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        if (!job.isActive) {
            job = viewModelScope.launch {
                //heavy process 
                //once done it will become inactive
            }
        }
    }
}
```